# Стилизация .md-документов

Tags: visual-studio-code, pdf, markdown

Использую `VSCode` для написания и выгрузки документов из `.md`-формата в форматы `html` (для публичных ресурсов) и `pdf` (для внутренней документации). Расширение использую вот это - [Markdown PDF](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf).

Появилась необходимость стилизовать страницы в pdf-документе. То есть надо добавить на каждую страницу лого в верху и в бэкграунд добавить полупрозрачную картинку.

Соответственно с `html` решается задача очень просто добавлением ссылки на картинки и добавлением одного .css файла.

Но как стилизовать страницы в pdf, не могу найти. Нашел как добавлять только стили через css, но как добавить медиа файлы на каждую страницу? Кто может подсказать инструменты и методы решения данной задачи.